# DSolve - 2nd order Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the DE: $\partial^2 \phi(x)=\frac{\rho(x)}{\epsilon}$ with $ \rho\left(x\right)=0$ for $x<-L$; $ \rho\left(x\right)=\rho_a$ for $-L<x<0$; $ \rho\left(x\right)=\rho_b$ for $0<x<L$ and $ \rho\left(x\right)=0$ for $x>L$

and Neumann boundary condition $\partial_x\phi(\pm\infty)=0$. I'm trying to use the following command, but I got no response from Mathematica

```
 DSolve[{\[Phi]''[x] == 1/\[Epsilon]d \[Rho][x] + NeumannValue[0, x < -1000000] + NeumannValue[0, x > 1000000]},\[Phi][x],x]
```

Thank you very much for the help.
Best,

Comment: Is this what you want?: `DSolve[{\[Phi]''[x] == 
   1/\[Epsilon]d Piecewise[{{\[Rho]a, -L < x <= 0}, {\[Rho]b, 
       0 < x < L}}]}, \[Phi], x, 
 Assumptions -> L > 0 && {\[Rho]a, \[Rho]b} \[Element] Reals]` -- You can get the derivative to vanish at one infinity but not the other.

Comment: Yes, it is precisely that. 
I have already defined $\rho(x)$ as Piecewise function.. So my problem concerns how to implement the Neumann condition within the DSolve command.. For instance, I'd like to use $\partial_x \phi(\pm \infty)=0$

Comment: Isn't the solution found by integrating $\frac{\rho(x)}{\epsilon}$ twice? So the general solution is the (double) antiderivative plus $c_1x+c_2$.  I don't see how to get $\phi_x$ to vanish at both $\pm\infty$ with only one free parameter $c_1$ (except by accident, say depending on $\rho_a$, $\rho_b$).

Comment: You are correct.. 
For $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$ the solution is given by $c_1 x + c_2$.. Then, by imposing $\partial_x \phi (\pm \infty) = 0$ we obtain $c_1=0$, so that the DE is undetermined by the constant $c_2$.. 

How can be possible to give two Neumann boundary condition and just get one constant? I'm puzzling with this.. Thanks.

Comment: If $\rho_a = -\rho_b$ and you set `C[2] -> -((L (\[Rho]a + \[Rho]b))/\[Epsilon]d)` in my `DSolve` code, then the solution vanishes at both $\pm\infty$.  I don't think it can be done for arbitrary values of the parameters.  But maybe I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Ok.. but how can be possible to give two Neumann boundary condition and just get one constant value?

Comment: If you're asking how to specify a Neumann problem in `DSolve`, the docs show the conditions only using explicit equations, like this: `DSolve[{u''[x] == u[x], u'[-1] == 2, u'[1] == 1}, u, x]` or `DSolve[{u''[x] == 1, u'[-1] == 2, u'[1] == 1}, u, x]`.